# Example of a series of functions that converges for Leibniz rule but is not uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Is there a series of functions $\sum (-1)^n u_n(x)$ that is convergent for [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) (alternating series test) in some interval but it is not **uniformly** convergent?

In particular the series must be (for using Leibniz rule)

- positive $(u_n(x) \geq 0)$
- decreasing $(u_{n+1}(x)\leq u_n(x))$
- such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n(x)=0$

---

**Edit**: I refer to the following definition: a series of function is uniformly convergent in a subset $S$ if

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in S} |\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n(x) -\sum_{n=0}^{N} u_n(x)| =0$$

Comment: Which rule are you referring to, specifically? (I am used to Leibniz's rule being a name for the [alternating series criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test))

Comment: It's $u_n(x),$ not $u(x)_n.$ Please edit.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm guessing he means $\sum (-1)^nu_n(x)$

Comment: Wow, that's quite a far cry from what's written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$u_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}, \quad n\in\mathbb N.$$ Then $u_n: [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a decreasing sequence of non-negative functions.

Clearly
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty,
$$
while
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nu_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}=-\log(1+x),
\quad\text{for all $x\in [0,1]$.}
$$
In fact,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^ku_k(x)=-\log(1+x)-\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\xi^{n+1}}{n+1},
\quad \text{for some $\xi\in (0,x)$},
$$
and thus
$$
\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^ku_k(x)+\log(1+x)\,\bigg|\le\frac{1}{n+1},
\quad \text{for all $x\in [0,1]$},
$$
i.e., the series $\,\sum (-1)^nu_n\,$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$.

Note. That the advantage of this example is that $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u_n(x)=e^{-nx}$ where $x\in I=(0,1]$ then

$$R_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^k u_k(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1} e^{-(n+1)x}}{1+e^{-x}}$$
so
$$\Vert R_n\Vert_\infty=\sup_{x\in I}\vert R_n(x)\vert\ge \frac12$$
so the convergence isn't uniform on $I$

Comment: We could also use $u_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1)$ - perhaps a bit more elementary.

Comment: is you result true for any decreasing $u_n(x)$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: If $u_n$ is decreasing then we have $$\left\vert\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^ku_k(x)\right\vert\le \vert u_{n+1}(x)\vert$$ and in the case where $sup\vert u_n(x)\vert$ tends to 0 we use the above inequality to prove the uniform convergence of the series. @DuFong